# How to clean a text inside textAreaInput() before some operation?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to clean a text write inside a `textAreaInput()` after a `writeLines` operation using the function `updateTextInput` without success. In my example:

```
# Packages
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)


# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textAreaInput("text_input","Write something"),
      actionButton("erefunction", "Erase")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("idSaida")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  
  observeEvent(input$erefunction, {
    
    filePath <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
    writeLines(c(input$text_input), filePath)
    updateTextInput(value="")
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

Please, any tips or a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `updateTextInput` use `updateTextAreaInput`; you also need to add a `session` to your shiny `server` function and pass that on to `updateTextAreaInput`.

Here is the revised `server` function:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$erefunction, {
        
        filePath <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
        writeLines(c(input$text_input), filePath)
        updateTextAreaInput(session, "text_input", value="")
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the session parameter and the id so updateSelectInput knows what input is being updated.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)


# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
    titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard"),  
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textAreaInput("text_input","Write something"),
            actionButton("erefunction", "Erase")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            textOutput("idSaida")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$erefunction, {
        
        filePath <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
        writeLines(c(input$text_input), filePath)
        ##added session and the name of the input to update
        updateTextInput(session, "text_input",  value="")
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```